# Next Step for Self-Learning

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I am an undergraduate mathematics major and recently completed a course in real analysis. While I enjoyed this course it left out many topics that I would have liked to learn because of time constraints. These included Riemann integration, sequences of functions, and series along with their convergence. Along with learning these topics I would like to get a more general idea of the topics we did cover using only the normal Euclidean absolute value metric. The course felt incomplete at times because this is not the only available way to think of distance but just the standard way. These topics include sequences, limits and continuous functions. Would it be recommended to study a subject such as metric spaces or topology in order to get a more abstract view of the topics that were covered in the course? If this is a good course of action should I fill the gaps from the topics that weren't covered before embarking on this or are those topics not so important in metric spaces and topology? Thank you for any answers.

Comment: It is definitely important to study metric spaces at some point, as well as the other topics you mentioned. Whether that's now or later depends on your priorities. But if you have time, it would make sense to do it now. You could use one of the standard analysis textbooks like Rudin or Apostol. The integration theory in those books is a bit more complicated than plain Riemann integrals, so you might want to complement your reading with the integration chapter from a rigorous calculus book like Spivak's. Also, they don't cover surface integrals properly. (Rudin does do them, but strangely.)...

Comment: To answer your question directly, no, you don't need to fill the gaps before jumping straight into metric spaces. On the contrary, studying these topics from books that do metric spaces first will bring greater clarity by focusing attention on the important points and providing useful insights and vocabulary from topology.

Comment: @David Thank you for your comments! It seemed the whole semester we were getting bogged down in details of the Euclidean metric instead of focusing on which metric theorems end up being true or false in. I've been thinking about reading the relevant chapters of Rudin over my winter break. Do you think this is the best course of action or a book on topology like Munkres?

Comment: I think it would make the most sense to use Rudin or Apostol. Most people can learn the topology they need from the introductory chapters of good analysis books. They don't need a whole book on topology, when what they need most is to see it applied to analysis. Also, I think it's better for most people to start with metric spaces rather than topological spaces.